# Animating a camera to turn around the player, then continue tracking player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So to explain what I'm trying to achieve, I'm using the "E" key to rotate the camera 90 degrees around the player and then continue tracking the player. I have no idea how to do it smoothly - so far, I've tried animations which stop the camera tracking the player, and animations return back to the original position once the animation is complete.

Here is my current code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TCam : MonoBehaviour {


    public Transform target;
    private Animator animator;
    private Vector3 positionOffset ;

    int i =0;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        //positionOffset = target.transform.position + transform.position;
        positionOffset = new Vector3(-10, 10,0);
        animator = GetComponent<Animator> ();
        animator.enabled = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.E)) {
            animator.SetTrigger ("switch");

            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (45, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y + 90, 0);
            target.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (45, target.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y + 90, 0);

            if (i == 0) {
                positionOffset = new Vector3 (0, 10, 10);
                i++;
            } else if (i == 1) {
                positionOffset = new Vector3 (10, 10, 0);
                i++;
            } else if (i == 2) {
                positionOffset = new Vector3 (0, 10, -10);
                i++;
            } else if (i == 3) {
                positionOffset = new Vector3 (-10, 10, 0);
                i = 0;
            }
        } else if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Q)) {
            transform.Rotate (-45, 0, 0);
            transform.Rotate (0, -90, 0);
            transform.Rotate (45, 0, 0);

            target.transform.Rotate (-45, 0, 0);
            target.transform.Rotate (0, -90, 0);
            target.transform.Rotate (45, 0, 0);
        }
        transform.position = target.position + positionOffset;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify: your core problem is to rotate the camera around the player smoothly when 'E' is pressed; and animation is a separate thing. Am I reading it correctly?

Comment: @andeart sorry to make it confusing, i mean i tried animating the camera from the animation window however when i did i couldn't get it to track the player, or if i could the animation would mess up when its was called from the code, but yes i would like to rotate the camera smoothly around the player by 90 degrees at a time.

Comment: Have you tried using http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html ?

Comment: @andeart yeah i have, however the problem is the camera is at 45 degrees, so when its rotated it looses sight of the player because it rotates around the local axis not the global

Comment: I think you're rotating it around itself. I've added some sample code in the answer below to help you get started.

Comment: Btw, if you haven't figured it out already, the second parameter in the Transform.RotateAround function takes in the axis around which you want to rotate. So if you know the up vector that you want it to rotate around, set it. And if you want it to angle downwards, you can immediately follow that with `Transform.LookAt()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting with the quaternions, try using the `Transorm.RotateAround()` method as follows:

```
transform.RotateAround(target.transform.position, Vector3.up, 40 * Time.deltaTime);
```

with conditions to stop when it's 90 degrees past it's original rotation. Similarly, work backwards to move it back.

I hope that helps!